# iOS Simulator installed app location in Xcode 6.1

Tags: xcode, xcode-simulator

I am trying to locate the actual location of app installed on iOS Simulator. I am using OSX 10.9.4 with Xcode 6.1

Already tried looking Application Support folder but can't find the simulator location. Tried a bunch of different locations as well, but can't find anything. Any ideas where can I find it or where should I look in apple documentation regarding this? Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For newer Xcode's (including 6.1) follow below steps to see the installed apps (.app) location >>

1. Right click Xcode.app.
2. Go to 'Show Contents'.
3. Navigate to this part of the file path: Contents > Developer > Platforms > iPhoneSimulator.platform > Developer > SDKs > iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk > Applications

Here will show all installed .app list.

Besides if you want to install new .app on simulator, just drag and drop .app to this location.

Answer (score 6):

After some more research I figured out that Apple changed it to be inside `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices`

Based on the ID of device, we can now go into that folder and find the `.app` file.

Comment: Please put your answer as an edit to your original question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way: Use [SimPholders2](http://simpholders.com). It's a little utility that lets you:

- Access all application folders from status item menu
- Quickly reset app storage by deleting files in Library and Documents (<kbd>⌃</kbd> + Click)
- Detailed information of file size and number of items in app bundle (<kbd>⇧</kbd>)
- Launch app directly in iPhone Simulator

[image]

Comment: Although I haven't mentioned in the question, I don't want to use any external utility :)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create a shortcut to the simulator app, you can do the following:

1. Control-click xcode.app in Applications and select "Show Package Contents"
2. Navigate to: Contents/Developer/Applications
3. Control-click iOS Simulator.app and select "Make Alias", or just drag it to the dock to create an alias there.

I'm using OS 10.9.5 and xCode 6.1.1